# avoid maximum prompts for SKStoreReview during testing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, skstorereviewcontroller

SKStoreReview for prompting users to review your iOS app has a 3 prompts per 365 days limit.

[SKStoreReview docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews)

Does this limit apply to testing locally? I'm working on my app and want to ensure I don't hit my limit after 3 tries myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`requestReview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) documentation:

> **Note**
>
> When you call this method while your app is still in development mode, a rating/review request view is always displayed so that you can test the user interface and experience. However, this method has no effect when you call it in an app that you distribute using TestFlight.

So you can safely test the review request process without any limits.